# How to send Automated Email when specific Excel cell value reached due date

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I've excel sheet (invoice) , i am updating client invoice and bill status regularly , i need to send remainder email to my client before bill reaches credit date (before 7 days) (only Pending bills), i am manually sending the email so far to my clients,

is there any option that automated email can send from excel before due date reaches (7days before and 3 days before) , could any one help me

[Email Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvE9C.jpg)
[Excel Sheet Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqY7g.jpg)

Comment: If you mean by "automated" that an email is sent without opening Excel and starting the Excel file you are showing in the above post then the answer is no. Yet, if you are willing to open the above file **each day** to check if any of the credits have expired (the checking part can be automated of course) then the answer is yes. Yet, in the latter of the two cases we'd expect some coding attempts on your side to resolve the issue yourself. After all, this website is not a free "code for me" service. Instead, we strive to help fellow programmers with **their** code.

Comment: @Ralph _without opening Excel_ Actually it's possible to make a data connection to the Excel workbook and check if emails need to be sent; and if they do, automate Outlook into sending them. This can be initiated from WSH or from Powershell without actually opening Excel. Also, this script could be run as a Scheduled Task once a day. (This has the added benefit of not including any macros in the Excel file.)

Comment: @ZevSpitz Sure, if you want to be smart about it: I can also think of more than 20 different applications / solutions which are able to read Excel files and capable to automatically send emails (based on the info in these Excel files). We could even setup an SQL Server with SSIS and SSRS to automate sending those emails. But if you go about any problem on this website like this then the answer would be (almost) always: yes, it can be done! But I (personally) believe that the OP was merely asking about Excel and not about the 20+ possible solutions which we could think of.

Comment: @Ralph I doubt it's worth the hour-long install of SQL Server and the consumption of system resources involved in running an instance of SQL Server (it might be faster to write the notices by hand and send them by post...). OTOH both WSH and Powershell are installed on every semi-modern Windows machine, do not consume any resources when the script has finished running, and use almost the same code that would be used when writing in VBA inside Excel.

Comment: @ZevSpitz My SQL installations normally take about 20 minutes (and all outbound emails are automatically logged, great feature). Anyway, be it as it may. This website [is not a discussion forum](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) but strives to provide straight answers to the posted questions. So, if you believe to have a feasible solution for the OP then feel free to post it. I will be also very interested to have a look at it. Otherwise, well...

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want!

To run a macro automatic when you manual change a specific cell you can use the Change event in a worksheet module.The example on this page use Cell A1 and will run the macro if the cell value >200.

1) Right click on a sheet tab and choose view code
2) Paste the event below in the sheet module.
3) Alt-q to go back to Excel

Note: Change YourMacroName to the name of your macro in the code.
If you want the code to work for another cell or more cells you can change the range in the event.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Not Application.Intersect(Range("A1"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value > 200 Then
            Call YourMacroName
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Example mail macro

Test this example macro to create/display a Outlook mail with a small text message.
You must copy this macro in a standard module and not in the worksheet module, see this page how.

Note: I use .Display in the code to display the mail, you can change that to .Send

Do not forget to change Call YourMacroName to Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook in the Change event.

```
Sub Mail_small_Text_Outlook()
'For Tips see: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winmail/Outlook/tips.htm
'Working in Excel 2000-2016
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim strbody As String

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    strbody = "Hi there" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "Cell A1 is changed" & vbNewLine & _
              "This is line 2" & vbNewLine & _
              "This is line 3" & vbNewLine & _
              "This is line 4"

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = "ron@debruin.nl"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "This is the Subject line"
        .Body = strbody
        'You can add a file like this
        '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
        .Display   'or use .Send
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail9.htm

Comment: Thank you , it works fine , i will do the modification as per my requirement ,